# Can't see Windows partition in Nautilus

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, windows, mount, ntfs

I am on Ubuntu 11.10, installed with Wubi. I used to be able to access my Windows partion from the list of devices in Nautilus, but I no longer see it. What might b.e wrong?

Running `sudo blkid` gives the following:

```
/dev/loop0: UUID="ef34b449-1330-4ac5-bb69-e1475c0b91da" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="PQSERVICE" UUID="D04C76D04C76B138" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="SYSTEM RESERVED" UUID="EC4878594878248C" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Acer" UUID="54947A5A947A3E94" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which **Ubuntu** version?  11.10, 11.04, 10.10, etc.

Comment: Somewhat lacking in information for us to help you. What does the output of `sudo blkid` show you for starters? (this will tell us if Ubuntu can see the Windows drive and what filesystem it is).

Comment: Do they appear listed in the Nautilus pane but you can't mount them?

Comment: I only see "SYSTEM RESERVED" listed, but it is some kind of boot partition - it does not contain my Windows files and folders.

Comment: Was you last shutdown of Windows clean? Or did it it freeze, bluescreen, get powered off before shutting down? Or was it hibernated?

Comment: Yes, last shutdown was clean. I rebooted into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be mounted as `/host` already.

Comment: Is that because you are using Wubi?

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to manually add the Windows partition using Nautilus.  It should appear (at top left) under Devices as 'OS'

To add automatically (or possibly at startup), you need to identify what logical drive it is:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If will be of type **ntfs**, and not be the smaller boot partition.

Then first create the mount point (target directory), and then mount the partition.  For my PC it is on: **/dev/sda2** (adjust to suit):

```
sudo mkdir /media/OS

sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /media/OS
```

Comment: This is what I get when executing that command:
`Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.`

Note that I installed Ubuntu using Wubi.

Comment: What do you see with: **ls -l /media**

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2011-11-28 18:21 windows` (That's what I called the mount point.)